# Is there any way to link it back to the menu after the user has chose the option

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there an easier way to loop back the option to the main menu? How do i do it?

```
from collections import Counter 
print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
print ("1.People")
print ("2.Name")
print ("3. Country")
print ("4. Continent")
opt = int(input("Enter option: "))
if opt ==1:
  print ("People")
from collections import Counter 
counterY = Counter()
with open('json.txt') as f:
        for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            splits = line.split(';')
            people = int(splits[3])
            counter1[name] += people
for name, pop_sum in counter1.most_common():
    print(Name, ":", pop_sum)
elif opt == 2:
  from collections import Counter 
counterx = Counter()
with open("json.txt") as f:
    for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
    for line in f:
        splits = line.split(';')
        change = float(splits[6])
        country = splits[1].strip()
        counter2[country] += change      
#Percentage Change By Countries"
print()
print ("Countries"):
    print(country)
```

Is there an easier way to loop back the option to the main menu? How do i do it?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the code in a while loop? You could have a 4th option be 'exit' that kicks you out of the loop/closes the program when used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Just wrap around your code in a while(True) and if one option matches the 4, it will end the program, otherwise it will print the main menu again.

PS: I got your main menu in a function so that your code could be more readable.

```
import turtle
from collections import Counter 

def main_menu():
    print(30 * '-')
    print("   M A I N - M E N U")
    print(30 * '-')
    print("1.Total Populations of the different continents & Continent with the lowest Population")
    print("2.Percentage Change(%) for different countries")
    print("3. Choose a country")
    print("4. Exit")
    print(30 * '-')

while(True):
    main_menu()
    opt = int(input("Enter option: "))
    if opt ==1:
        print("Continents Sorted By Population")
        from collections import Counter 
        counter1 = Counter()
        with open('demo.txt') as f:
            for i in range(0,2):
                next(f)
            for line in f:
                splits = line.split(';')
                population = int(splits[3])
                continent = splits[-1].strip()
                counter1[continent] += population
            # Print continents sorted by population
            for continent, pop_sum in counter1.most_common():
                print(continent, ":", pop_sum)
     #Finding continent with lowest population
        counter3 = Counter()
        with open("demo.txt") as f:
            for i in range(0,2):
                next(f)
            for line in f:
                counter3[continent] += population
        for continent, pop_total in counter3.most_common():
            print()
            print("Continent with the Lowest Population")
            print(continent,":", pop_sum)
            print()
    elif opt == 2:
        from collections import Counter
        counter2 = Counter()
        with open("demo.txt") as f:
            for i in range(0,2):
                next(f)
            for line in f:
                splits = line.split(';')
                change = float(splits[6])
                country = splits[1].strip()
                counter2[country] += change      
        #Percentage Change By Countries"
        print()
        print("Percentage Change By Countries")
        for country, change_sum in counter2.most_common():
            print(country, change_sum,"%")
    elif opt == 4:
        break

def file_search():
        userInput = input('Enter a country: ').lower()
        result = []
        with open("demo.txt", 'r') as f:
            for x in f:
                if userInput in x.lower():
                    result.append(x.split(';'))
        for s in result:
            print(s[1] + " \nCountry Rank: "+ s[0]+ " \n2019 population: " + s[3] + "\nPopulation change(%)"+s[6]+"\nContinent:  "+ s[7])
file_search()
```

Comment: Thank you, however, i keep getting this error: def : main menu expected an indented block, i have tried to move the codes but it's not working

Comment: i still get the main menu not defined error/sorry for the rush, i am about to submit this in school.

Comment: Just in time ! THANK YOU ! :)